# Deploy Rasa in Docker

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose, dockerfile, rasa

I'm new to Rasa and Docker I want to deploy my rasa project in Docker. I can't find right flow for deployment. what I understood for deployment from blogs and docker videos and tried like this.

First step: I have to create a docker image contains project source and requirements.

Dockerfile

```
FROM rasa/rasa  
COPY . /chatbot  
WORKDIR /chatbot  
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt  
USER root  
COPY ./actions /app/actions
USER 1001
```

requirements.txt

```
pyaml  
flask   
requests  
spacy  
rasa-nlu   
rasa-core   
rasa-core-sdk
```

Second step: Create Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.0"  
services:  
  rasa:  
    image: rasa/rasa:2.6.3-full  
    ports:   
      - 5005:5005  
    volumes:   
      - ./:/app  
    command:  
      - run  
      - -m  
      - models   
      - --enable-api  
      - --cors   
      - "*"  
      - --debug   
  action_server:  
    image: rasa/rasa_core_sdk:latest  
    ports:  
      - 5055:5055  
    volumes:  
      - ./actions:/app/actions  
   command:  
     - rasa  
     - run  
     - actions
```

Can anyone tell me right flow for deployment.

Comment: Could you, please, describe the exact problem you faced? Do you have some error messages or an expected outcome?

Answer (score 4):

Installed docker and docker-compose on your system.

Create the first Dockerfile (just a new file with name “Dockerfile”) in root directory of the project and should have this content -

```
FROM rasa/rasa:2.8.0
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY . /app
USER root
# WORKDIR /app
# COPY . /app
COPY ./data /app/data
RUN  rasa train
VOLUME /app
VOLUME /app/data
VOLUME /app/models
CMD ["run","-m","/app/models","--enable-api","--cors","*","--debug" ,"--endpoints", "endpoints.yml", "--log-file", "out.log", "--debug"]
```

Note that you can change the rasa version here.

Create second Dockerfile in actions folder and place this content -

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:2.8.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
USER root
RUN pip install --verbose -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5055
USER 1001
```

Note that you have to put requirements.txt file containing python libraries that you installed and used in the actions folder.

So, That was all the dockerfiles we needed, now in the root directory, you can see a file called endpoints.yml. change the name localhost to action_server (we’ll register this name in the docker-compose file for container of action server) in the action_endpoint and it should look like -

```
action_endpoint:
 url: "http://action_server:5055/webhook"
```

Finally, create a docker-compose.yml file in the root directory and place these content -

```
version: '3'
services:
    rasa:
      container_name: "rasa_server"
      user: root
      build: 
        context:  .
      volumes:
      - "./:/app"
      ports: 
        - "5005:5005"
    action_server:
      container_name: "action_server"
      build: 
        context: actions
      volumes:
        - ./actions:/app/actions
        - ./data:/app/data
      ports:
        - 5055:5055
```

After all this you can just run the command

```
docker-compose up --build
```

credits: https://forum.rasa.com/t/dockerizing-my-rasa-chatbot-application-that-has-botfront/46096/27

Comment: If you're deploying those containers on azure app services, it will fail as azure app services do not support *build* in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me. I followed the same structure, except the commands in action_server (inside docker-compose.yml) . I skipped the command part, it was working fine.

```
  action-server:
    image: rasa/rasa-sdk:1.10.2
    volumes:
      - ./actions:/app/actions
    ports:
      - 5055:5055
```

And in endpoints URL, the name of the service i.e. `action_server` will only come

Comment: Using the name of the service not working. Instead if we give the IP address of the host it works. But will be a problem when running in Azure webapp. As we don't have IP address to give in Azure. Why giving `http://localhost:5055/webhook` or `http://servicename:5055/webhook` doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

This also works like a charme:

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
   rasa:
   image: rasa/rasa:3.5.5
   ports:
     - 5005:5005
   volumes:
     - ../RetrieverReader/:/app
   command: 
     - run
     - --enable-api
     - --cors
     - '*'
   action-server:
   build: 
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile.action-server
   volumes:
     - ../RetrieverReader/actions:/app/actions
   ports:
     - 5055:5055
   command:
     - start
     - -vv
     - --actions
     - actions
     - --cors
     - '*'
```

The Dockerfile.actions-server I just used to install my dependencies:

```
FROM rasa/rasa-sdk:3.5.4
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
USER root
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --verbose -r requirements.txt
```

Of course you can use docker-compose up to build and start

```
docker-compose up --build
```

The command --cors * in the action server is especially necessary if you want to directly access your Action-Server from your frontend

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a correct way to deploy your bot using docker. What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Not able to connect action server. I changed my endpoints url into action_server